# Using CSS :nth-child to create loop with 5 different designs repeated every 5 items

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I’m trying to achieve a very specific grid to showcase some items. The idea is to create a repeating loop with 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th item that have a different styling (and the styling repeats afterwards).

For example: 1st red background / 2nd blue background / 3rd green background / 4th yellow background / 5th black background and it loops for the number of projects (may it be 5 or 28). You would therefore have : #1 red / #2 blue / #3 green / #4 yellow / #5 black / #6 red / #7 blue / #8 green / #9 yellow etc

I would like to use plain CSS to create this loop. I use webflow so the content is populated 1 by 1 in a list and I need to tweak the base styling according to position in list.

What i've tried so far is using nth-child like so :

```css
.collection-list:nth-child(2n) .collection-item {}
.collection-list:nth-child(3n) .collection-item {}
.collection-list:nth-child(4n) .collection-item {}
.collection-list:nth-child(5n) .collection-item {}
```

It works for the 5 first items… but…
My problem is, it doesn’t exactly seem to work as a loop… and I suppose it’s because 2n and 3n sometimes conflict (for instance when you have 2*3). And I can’t use odd and even with nth-child because the idea is to have it loop only after 5 items…

Does anyone have a genious idea for that ? Is it even possible by just using CSS ?

Thanks!

Comment: *Is it even possible by just using CSS ?*       Yes, see answers below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you're defining the formula. The formula in the nth-child selector goes as follows:

```
nth-child(an+b)
```

Where a is the size of your cycle (in your case, 5), and b is the offset value (or modulo).

Here's a working snippet:

```css
.collection-list:nth-child(5n+0) .collection-item {background-color: red;}
.collection-list:nth-child(5n+1) .collection-item {background-color: blue;}
.collection-list:nth-child(5n+2) .collection-item {background-color: green;}
.collection-list:nth-child(5n+3) .collection-item {background-color: yellow;}
.collection-list:nth-child(5n+4) .collection-item {background-color: purple;}
```

```html
<div class="collection-list"><div class="collection-item">1</div></div>
<div class="collection-list"><div class="collection-item">2</div></div>
<div class="collection-list"><div class="collection-item">3</div></div>
<div class="collection-list"><div class="collection-item">4</div></div>
<div class="collection-list"><div class="collection-item">5</div></div>
<div class="collection-list"><div class="collection-item">6</div></div>
<div class="collection-list"><div class="collection-item">7</div></div>
<div class="collection-list"><div class="collection-item">8</div></div>
<div class="collection-list"><div class="collection-item">9</div></div>
<div class="collection-list"><div class="collection-item">10</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Really short answer :

- You're confusing `2n`, `3n`, `4n`, ...
- With `5n`, `5n+1`, `5n+2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a repeat pattern based on 5, this were you need to start from `5n` then minus or plus to select the sibling you want to style.

example:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: divs;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div:nth-child(1n) {
  counter-increment: divs;
  background: purple;
  min-width: 20%;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px;
}

div:before {
  content: counter(divs);
  padding: 1em;
}

body :nth-child(5n - 3) {
  background: yellow;
}

body :nth-child(5n - 2) {
  background: pink;
}

body :nth-child(5n - 1) {
  background: lime;
}

body :nth-child(5n) {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```